# How to conduct pairwise comparison in R like that in SPSS with "multcomp" package

Tags: r

I have three factors: word, type and register. In SPSS, it is very easy to conduct a pairwise comparison (or simple comparison) in SPSS, the syntax is:

```
/EMMEANS=TABLES(word*register*type) COMPARE(type) ADJ (BONFERRONI)
```

And it will give me a result like this:

[image]

But how can I achieve this in R with Multcomp package? Say if I have a anova result like this:

```
library (multcomp)
anova <- aov (data, min~word*register*type)
summary (anova)
```

How can I do SPSS-like pairwise comparisons?

Comment: Have you seen `?pairwise.t.test` and its `p.adjust.method=` argument?

Answer (score 1):

```
hsb2<-read.table("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv", sep=",", header=T)
attach(hsb2) # attach is a horrible practice, but just roll with it for this example
pairwise.t.test(write, ses, p.adj = "bonf")
```

That gives you the Bonferonni pairwise comparison that you see in SPSS.

This may help further and in general UCLA provides some good resources that relate commands in SAS, SPSS, Stata, Mplus and R:

http://statistics.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/posthoc.htm

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/dae/

So, that's for pairwise comparisons. You can also use `p.adjust` with multiple comparisons (multi-way). See this manual page "[Adjust P-values for Multiple Comparisons](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html)".

The example they give showing the different adjustments which can be made, including Bonferroni, is:

```
require(graphics)

set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(50, mean = c(rep(0, 25), rep(3, 25)))
p <- 2*pnorm(sort(-abs(x)))

round(p, 3)
round(p.adjust(p), 3)
round(p.adjust(p, "BH"), 3)

## or all of them at once (dropping the "fdr" alias):
p.adjust.M <- p.adjust.methods[p.adjust.methods != "fdr"]
p.adj    <- sapply(p.adjust.M, function(meth) p.adjust(p, meth))
p.adj.60 <- sapply(p.adjust.M, function(meth) p.adjust(p, meth, n = 60))
stopifnot(identical(p.adj[,"none"], p), p.adj <= p.adj.60)
round(p.adj, 3)
## or a bit nicer:
noquote(apply(p.adj, 2, format.pval, digits = 3))


## and a graphic:
matplot(p, p.adj, ylab="p.adjust(p, meth)", type = "l", asp = 1, lty = 1:6,
        main = "P-value adjustments")
legend(0.7, 0.6, p.adjust.M, col = 1:6, lty = 1:6)

## Can work with NA's:
pN <- p; iN <- c(46, 47); pN[iN] <- NA
pN.a <- sapply(p.adjust.M, function(meth) p.adjust(pN, meth))
## The smallest 20 P-values all affected by the NA's :
round((pN.a / p.adj)[1:20, ] , 4)
```

[This page](http://rtutorialseries.blogspot.com/2011/03/r-tutorial-series-anova-pairwise.html) also gives some nice pairwise comparison examples with ANOVA where they have `mental`, `physical`, and `medical` factors and adjust the p-values in various ways.

[This](http://www.ievbras.ru/ecostat/Kiril/R/Biblio/R_eng/Bretz%20Multiple%20Comparisons.pdf) is another excellent resource by Bretz.

Finally, here's a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557286/n-way-anova-in-r) on N-way ANOVA in R where they show how to do 3-way and up to 100-way.

Comment: Thank you for you anwser! But the example you gave me is just two-way interactions. How can I do that in three-way interactions, which is much different with two-way comparison.

Comment: @PingTang Updated my answer. I hope some part of it is useful.